# ActionController::ParameterMissing in UsersController#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want the user to sign up to the application, but I get this error show below,

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in UsersController#show
param is missing or the value is empty: user
```

`users_controller.rb`:

```js
def show
  @user = User.new(user_params)
end

def new
  @user = User.new
end

def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

private

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

Comment: Where is the "UsersController#show" content?

Comment: I bet you called `user_params` somewhere in your `UsersController#show`.

Comment: Yes, I have called the method user_params in UsersController#show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `user_params` method in your `show` action, that requires the `user` param to be present in the `params` hash. But, it's not really present for the corresponding request of the `show` action. That's why you got that mentioned error:

```
param is missing or the value is empty: user
```

To fix your issue, change your `show` method to this:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

This is just grabbing the `id` of the user from the `params` hash and then find that user from the database using the `User.find` call.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you call user_params at show action. Normaly request to show action only have one params is id of user. Here you call user_params it will search params correspond attributes of user model then turn they into new method, but they are not exist. Therefore it raise error for you.
I think at show action you only write:

`def show
  @user = User.find params[:id]
  @new_user = User.new    #if you need create 1 form at show view
end`